# Compare MANY columns in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

I have a table with some denormalized data for a specific purpose (don't ask), so it has several hundred columns. There is a primary key.

This table is updated weekly, but most id:s will have the same data as the week before.

Now, I need to store all record versions in a history table, i.e. if record with id X is added week N, no changes week N+1 but some data changed week N+2 and N+3, then the history table should contain three records: Those from weeks N, N+2 and N+3.

It's technically easy to write the appropriate `insert` query, but it would involve comparison of each column, so it will be a very long SQL query. I'm sure it would work, but...

Is there any way in MySQL to compare ALL columns without explicitly writing `...or t1.col1 <> t2.col1...` for each column? I.e. something like `...t1.allcolumns <> t2.allcolumns...`, like comparing the entire row in one go?

I'm pretty sure the answer is no, but... :-)

Comment: Whoever designed your schema was thinking of a spreadsheet, not a relational database; that is what is making your life miserable.  Maybe it is time to reimplement the database perhaps using an [EAV schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model)?

Comment: It's for a specific purpose that requires that it's the way it is. I will not discuss it because it's lengthy and beside the point.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a program (in your favourite programming language) to build the query. The program would look in the schema for the database, find all the columns of the table, and construct the query from that. I don't think it is possible to do that in plain SQL, but even if possible, plain SQL is probably the wrong tool.

Comment: Yes, of course. Generating the correct SQL can be done in several different ways. I'll probably use keyboard macros in Notepad++ based on the DML for the table. Thanks for the idea, but doesn't really address the problem (avoiding the huge SQL).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the row-values syntax, but you still have to name all columns:

```
(t1.col1, t1.col2, ...) <> (t2.col1, t2.col2, ...)
```

Comment: Ah, that might be of interest. Will look it up, especially how it treats `null`.

Comment: The handling of null is done by the `<>` operator. `null` is not considered `<>` from `null` (the result of the comparison is *unknown*). If you want `null` to be treated to be the same as `null`, you have to use the `<=>` operator `not (...) <=> (...)` (never used that, hope it works): https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to

Answer (score 0):

**Update 1**

Check this out: https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/intersect.php

1. Intersect t1 and t2. Result = rows on both tables.
2. Select all fiends from t1 not in your intersect result.

Sorry for the lack of code, I don't have time to elaborate, but that's the idea.

Comment: Not really, I think. I don't need to get distinct rows, but rather insert `t1` records that have no identical record in `t2`. If you see a way to do that with `distinct`, then please elaborate.

Comment: @KjellRilbe I updated the answer reflecting what you want from your comment.

Comment: Thanks, "intersect" and "not in" would require a comparison of all fields, would it not? That's what my question was - how to avoid explicit comparison of all fields. Your previous suggestion to use distinct would indeed avoid that, but I fail to see how I could use that to insert the t1 records into t2, that are not present there.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp --> SELECT INTO t2 FROM (SELECT [...] INTERSECT [...])

Comment: @KjellRilbe please let me know if that answer solved your issue, and mark whatever answer fits you as accepted eventually.

Comment: Istudied the `intersect` article. I understand that bit. But in your step 2, how do I select the t1 records not in the intersection set without explicitly listing all column names? That's what I'm trying to avoid, and I can't see how the intersection helps, compared to simply checking against t2 directly.